# Execute the method after volley response is received

Tags: java, android, android-volley

When I run the following code,
I get "blank" in the log, whereas I want it 'volleyResult' to be set to the response generated by volley request.

However when I run same code for second time, it shows correctly.

So, How to hold "Log.i(--)" in 'courses' method to execute until the volleyResult has arrived.

I have several methods just like 'courses', the only difference between them is the URL which they call.
Also they all are serving as 'OnButtonClickListner', so calling 'courses' inside 'req' isn't an option.

```
    String volleyResult = "blank";

    public void courses(View view) {
        String url = "http://courses/list.json";
        reqReturn(url, "Courses");
        Log.i("Volley Res", volleyResult);    
    }


    public void req(String url, final String type ) {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    volleyResult = response;
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            volleyResult = "error";
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Cookie", cookie);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

Comment: Call course in onResponse of your volley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call courses() in onResponse()

**Edit to clarify:**

You fill the var volleyResult within your Response.Listener. This is asynchronous and the time it takes depends on the server delay and your internet connection. There are several ways to "hold" out your processing method that needs the result in volleyResult.

**The easiest way:**
Move the process (in your case the *Log.i("Volley Res", volleyResult);*  within the onResponse method, after you store the response in volleyResult.

A bit cleaner:
Move the your code into a new function and call it from your Response.Listener methods:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
  volleyResult = response;
  methodToHoldUntilResponseArrived();
}

public void methodToHoldUntilResponseArrived(){
  // your code that relies on the volley response
  Log.i("Volley Res", volleyResult);
}
```

**In case your courses method gets called repeatedly anyways:** You could set a flag when the data is received and place your code within courses() in an if-condition block:

```
private boolean mHasReceivedData = false;
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
  volleyResult = response;
  mHasReceivedData = true;
}

public void courses(View view){
  // your code that relies on the volley response
  if(mHasReceivedData){
        Log.i("Volley Res", volleyResult);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have nearly 10 methods just like 'courses', only thing that differs is the URL, and also 'courses' is serving as 'OnButtonClickListner'.

Comment: well, onResponse does get called when the server has successfully responded. Use this method to start any methods that rely on data from the server first

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11302112)

Comment: @msrd0 it is THE answer. He needs to call the method he wants to hold until a response is received, (i thought courses()) in, or after onResponse gets called. Because before onResponse got called, no value will be stored in his volleyResult var.

Answer (score 0):

Easyway - Put Log.i() inside the onResponse method

Other option is to use wait()/notify(). You would need a monitor object to hanlde everything.

```
 public synchronized void courses(View view) {
    String url = "http://courses/list.json";
    reqReturn(url, "Courses");
    wait();
    Log.i("Volley Res", volleyResult);    
}
```

And in onResponse

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                volleyResult = response;
                YourClass.this.notify();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Print the LOG on the OnResponse() method.
Also again call the Same API if Time Out Error occurs in the OnErrorResponse() method.